# Gigabit ethernet requires replug to work for kernel 4.20

Tags: linux-kernel, ethernet

I have a Microchip sama5d36 board that has a gigabit ethernet (KSZ9031RNX) and 10/100 ethernet (DP83848J).  When I use kernel 4.20 the gigabit ethernet wont connect until I unplug and replug the ethernet cable.  This issue only shows up with certain router connections and only shows up on the gigabit port.  The problem goes away if I switch back to kernel 4.18.  The dts files are identical and I don't see any changes in the config settings that seem significant.

Here is my dts setting:

```
        macb0: ethernet@f0028000 {
            phy-mode = "rgmii";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";

            ethernet-phy@7 {
                reg = <0x7>;
            };
        };
```

I am using systemd-networkd  and this is my setting in /etc/systemd/network:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

After restart:

```
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:1e:08:a0:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

After unplug and replug:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:1e:08:a0:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.6/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85532sec preferred_lft 85532sec
    inet6 fe80::21c:1eff:fe08:a0e1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any insight on where I might look to identify the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a bug. Try to upgrade to a newer kernel.

See https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.20.13
and https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg543703.html

> commit cbae90516d2a5fd3c71d55a28bacc5f67625564d
>   Author: Heiner Kallweit 
>   Date:   Thu Jan 10 20:22:26 2019 +0100
>
> net: phy: micrel: set soft_reset callback to genphy_soft_reset for
>   KSZ9031
>
> [ Upstream commit 1d16073a326891c2a964e4cb95bc18fbcafb5f74 ]
>
> So far genphy_soft_reset was used automatically if the PHY driver
>   didn't implement the soft_reset callback. This changed with the
>   mentioned commit and broke KSZ9031. To fix this configure the KSZ9031
>   PHY driver to use genphy_soft_reset.
>
> Fixes: 6e2d85ec0559 ("net: phy: Stop with excessive soft reset")
>   Reported-by: Tony Lindgren 
>   Signed-off-by: Heiner Kallweit 
>   Tested-by: Tony Lindgren 
>   Tested-by: Sekhar Nori 
>   Reviewed-by: Florian Fainelli 
>   Signed-off-by: David S. Miller 
>   Signed-off-by: Sasha Levin

Comment: Thanks for the information, that is very helpful.  I had tried 4.20.14 so might have to wait for the next revision...

Comment: seems there's a patch in 4.20.15 with an explanation and adding a new fix: [net: phy: Micrel KSZ8061: link failure after cable connect](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.20.15&id=ce176ac91ec71803aec12a97d741ffab642f0bf4)

Comment: So I tried 4.20.15 and the issue still exists, same thing for 4.20.12.  I will have to try some other iterations...